# Running interactive child shell program in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, stdout, stdin

I'm trying to run an interactive child shell program in node.js where the main process exits when the child process is done. It works perfectly fine if I do:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var child = spawn('npm', ['init'], { stdio: 'inherit' });
```

However, I would like to do a manual implementation and I'm having problems getting the process to terminate after the child program is done. Here's where I am at:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var child = spawn('npm', ['init']);

process.stdin.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('process.stdin!');
    child.stdin.write(data);
});

child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('child.stdout!');
    process.stdout.write(data);
});

// doesn't fire
child.on('close', function (code) {
    console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
    process.exit(code);
});

// doesn't fire
child.on('disconnect', function (code) {
    console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
    process.exit(code);
});

// doesn't fire
child.on('exit', function (code) {
    console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
    process.exit(code);
});
```

My knowledge of shell scripts is fairly limited, and it's not clear to me if the child process is not signaling that it's done, if I have to listen to another type of exit event, or if my entire approach for this use case is flawed. The desired behavior is that the main process exit after the child process is done (in this case after "npm init" is done with all the questions). This is for educational purposes only, please do not recommend an abstraction library.

Comment: shouldn't `child.on('close')` be `child.stdout.on('close')`?

Comment: Not as far as I know. I tried it anyway for good measure, but it yields nothing.